# Close parent fancybox window from child popup window

Tags: javascript

Borwser-click button- open fancybox--click a button on fancy box --open a new popup window

I want to back browser when I close last popup window. Is it possible?

Now I close fancybox popup manually. I need fancy box close automatically when I will close last pop window

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Can you post any code or even better a demo?